# How to organize vueify within laravel?

Tags: laravel, browserify, vue.js, laravel-elixir, ecma

I want to use Vueify in my Laravel project. I have different Vuejs components using Vueify (*.vue files). My question is about how to best organize the required files and also optimize JS code sent to browsers.

Basically I would like to use such components directly in my blade template that includes my Vue instance. But since I need to compile that *.vue files, I cannot reference them directly in my template. With that, I mean doing stuff like:

`import Timeline from "./components/Timeline.vue";`

within my blade template is not working.

Thus I created a dedicated JS file for each blade template where I store the Vue object that includes the components. This doesn't feel right. For example it make my gulp file looks like:

```
mix.browserify('models.js', 'public/js/compiled-models.js');
mix.browserify('campaigns.js', 'public/js/compiled-campaigns.js');
mix.browserify('campaigns_edit.js', 'public/js/compiled-campaigns_edit.js');
mix.browserify('product.js', 'public/js/compiled-product.js');
...
```

I hope you know what I mean. I did it like that, because I was afraid of combining all components to a single app.js file. I did not find any information about what is the way to go here.

Basically I would love to get rid of all *.js files because they are just my way to get components compiled down. Or, at least I do not want to create one file per "page".

How to organize this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution I was looking for. As already mentioned, I can bundle them together in a single file but I could not figure out how to exactly do that.

I now have an app.js looking like this:

```
window.Vue = require('vue');
require('vue-resource');

Vue.component('Repository', require('./product_images/Repository.vue'));
```

or, while using npm:

```
import vSelect from "vue-select"
Vue.component('v-select', vSelect);
```

Further, I register vuejs filters and directives in that file

And finally my gulpfile:

```
elixir(function (mix) {
    mix.webpack('app.js', {
        outputDir: "public/js",
        output: {
            filename: "compiled-[name].js"
        },
        module: {
            loaders: [{
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue'
            }, {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loader: 'babel',
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015']
                }
            }]
        },
        watchOptions: {
            poll: true
        }
    })
```

This leads to an app-compiled.js where all my components are registered without conflicting. In my blade files I simply use them in HTML without importing anything explicitly.

BTW: This is the way Laravel 5.3 is going for. There I finally figured it out, how to "pre-compile" all my vuejs components without any conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

How about bundling them all into one dist file and just use the Vue.js component you need in your Laravel view?

Comment: well, I am concerned of unnecessary data exchanged between server and client but maybe I just have too less confidences in client caching a big JS file at least during the whole session!?

Comment: That file definitely should be cached, there are several ways to set caching in the response header (PHP/Laravel, Apache, Nginx). Put a version number or unique identifier in a query string or file name appendix so the browser will load it again once the version changes. (In dev mode you can just disable cache, i.e. via browser dev tools)

Comment: What happens with the multiple Vue instances, all bound to "body"-tag in my case. Don't they conflict in this situation?

Comment: How about one main Vue.js instance containing all components and in HTML go with `<body><products></products><body>`. (Not sure how much of the unused components Vue.js loads/instanciates, but I'd expect it to be smart enough to just do what's necessary.) Other option is to use different ids: `<body id="#products"></body>`.